# set selected value of a asp dropdown with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I am trying to set the dropdown value with jquery when modal popup is displayed. 
I am trying with some static data but without any success.
This is what I have:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-EditSplitAgent", function () {
              var first = $(this).data('first');
              var last = $(this).data('last');
              var splitPC = $(this).data('splitpc');
              var id = $(this).data('id');
              $('#<%=txtFirstEdit.ClientID%>').val(first);
              $('#<%=txtLastEdit.ClientID%>').val(last);
              $('#<%=hfLifeID.ClientID%>').val(id);              
              $("#ddlAgentPercEdit").val('0.50');             
              $('#editSplitAgent').modal('show');
          });
```

The dropdown has this values:

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAgentPercEdit" runat="server">
                                   <asp:ListItem Value="">Select Percentage</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.50">0.5</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.75">0.75</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.9">0.01</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.7">0.7</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.1">0.1</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.8">0.8</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.6">0.6</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.9">0.9</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.05">0.05</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.95">0.95</asp:ListItem>
                             </asp:DropDownList>
```

I have textbox and hidden field which have the correct value when the modal popup is displayed.
As you can see in the jquery event I am trying static data just so I can see its working ok with static data, but originally I'll need to assign the splitPC var value to the dropdown value.
Thanks in advance for your advices,
Laziale

EDIT: 
rendered code for the modal popup:

```
        <div class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="editSplitAgent">
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Edit Split Agent</h3>   
  </div>
    <div class="modal-body">       
        <div class="content">

              <div class="form-row row-fluid">
                      <div class="span12">
                          <div class="row-fluid">
                               <label class="form-label span4" for="tooltip">First Name</label>
                               <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtFirstEdit" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFirstEdit" class="span8 tip" />       
                                 <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RequiredFieldValidator4" style="color:Red;display:none;"></span>
            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ValidatorCalloutExtender5_ClientState" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ValidatorCalloutExtender5_ClientState" />                                                        
                           </div>
                      </div> 
                </div>
                 <div class="form-row row-fluid">
                      <div class="span12">
                          <div class="row-fluid">
                               <label class="form-label span4" for="tooltip">Last Name</label>
                               <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtLastEdit" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtLastEdit" class="span8 tip" />  
                                   <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RequiredFieldValidator5" style="color:Red;display:none;"></span>
            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ValidatorCalloutExtender6_ClientState" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ValidatorCalloutExtender6_ClientState" />                                                         
                           </div>
                      </div> 
                </div>
             <div class="form-row row-fluid">
                      <div class="span12">
                          <div class="row-fluid">
                               <label class="form-label span4" for="tooltip">Agent Percentage</label>
                                 <div class="span8 controls">
                             <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlAgentPercEdit" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAgentPercEdit">
    <option value="">Select Percentage</option>
    <option value="0.50">0.5</option>
    <option value="0.75">0.75</option>
    <option value="0.9">0.01</option>
    <option value="0.7">0.7</option>
    <option value="0.1">0.1</option>
    <option value="0.8">0.8</option>
    <option value="0.6">0.6</option>
    <option value="0.9">0.9</option>
    <option value="0.05">0.05</option>
    <option value="0.95">0.95</option>

</select>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                      </div> 
                </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfLifeID" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hfLifeID" />
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `<%=ddlAgentPercEdit.ClientID%>`?

Comment: Why are you using `ClientID` for everything else but not for `ddlAgentPercEdit`?

Comment: I tried with ClientID at first but it wasn't working that way.

Comment: have you debugged your java script ?

Answer (score 4):

you should use

```
$("#<%=ddlAgentPercEdit.ClientID%>").val('0.50');
```

check my example on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y4jDy/)

Please paste your rendered html from your browser. I will help you fix it

Comment: its not working that way as well, I tried that already but thanks for your tip

Comment: rendered code for the modal popup included although I don't know how much it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be an issue ...

You seem to be setting the value of the dropdown , `before the Modal` is being shown ..

So theoretically speaking `your dropdown is not yet visible` when you are trying to set the value.

So try setting the value of the dropdown after the modal is shown..

```
 $('#editSplitAgent').modal('show');   // Show the modal first 
 $("[id*=ddlAgentPercEdit]").val('0.50');  // Then set the value
```

Comment: the way he binds the event is correct and it doesnt matter he binds them before or after

Comment: I am not correcting the way he is binding the event .. Initially when the event is bound , he is delegating the event .. Meaning the  `Modal  ` is not yet available on the page .. Meaning it will be dynamically added or set to 'display:none' at that point of time.. So if you set a value to a element which is hidden , nothing happens .. So that is the reason i was asking the OP to set the value of the dropdown after the Modal is shown